# Agregate function with multiple condition

Tags: mysql

how to achive in `mysql` sth like this:

```
select 
sum(B.someField) where B.someIntFild = 1
sum(B.someField) where B.someintFild = 2
from tableA A
inner join tableB B on A.id = B.id
where A.id = 'someId'
```

which are two sums on one group but first sum is for items with `someIntFild = 1` and second `someIntFild  = 2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, eg

```
sum(case when B.someIntFild = 1 then B.somefield else 0 end) as Col1,
sum(case when B.someIntFild = 2 then B.somefield else 0 end) as Col2
```

etc

Comment: fine for sum, but how about count ?

Comment: Well the same applies, but your question is not asking about *count*